# Dragging a CSS scaled element removes scaling (HTML5 dragging, not jquery)

Tags: html, html5-draggable

I'm creating a palette where objects can be dragged and dropped.  To support smaller screen sizes and avoid a ton of calculations, I'm trying to implement css scaling on the palette itself, or on the objects with them.

I'm using HTML draggable to drag the images.  However, when I drag on a scaled image, the scaling goes away, and it shows as the full size again.  This makes it very difficult to understand how things will drop.

Here's a code pen, where the blue box is scaled down to half size.

https://codepen.io/daprezjer/pen/xxYzdOM

And the code for it:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="dragging" draggable="true"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#dragging {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: scale(.5);
}
```

And here's a snapshot of that codepen when you start dragging the blue box.  You'll see the dragging preview doubles in size, back to it's original

[image]

Is there any way to keep the dragged image the same size as the scaled original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform: scale(.5);`

This line doesnt work while dragging. So better set the width and height directly using a responsive units.
Secondly, you can make use of @media queries to set the size of smaller devices.

Comment: Was hoping there was a different workaround but thanks for confirming that's what I'll have to do.